# Production grade Cassandra client configuration for Java application

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

My application runs with more than 100 transactions per second in production. I would like to know the configuration should be used to achieve this.

In non Prod environment i am using the cluster with DCAwareLoadBalancingPolocy and consistency level as LOCAL_QUORUM.

All remaining configuration is left as default.

Is the default configuration enough or i need to specify all the connection options like pooling options, socket options, consistency level, etc.,

PS:
Cassandra version 3
Please suggest how to scale it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java driver defaults are quite good, especially for that load. You need to use DCAware/TokenAware load balancing policy that is default. You may tune the connection pooling to allow more "in-flight" requests per single connection. You need to have only single instance of the `Session` class per application to avoid opening too many connections to cluster. The real performance gain comes from using the asynchronous operations, and having lower consistency level, like, `LOCAL_ONE` (but this is application specific).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am seeing an issue while the application is running, suddenly the session object is getting nullified. Because of this i am seeing the DB connection failure..How to get the session object created automatically, when it is broken? And what would be the reason for the session is getting nullified?

Comment: It's really depends on your application - if you keep session in something like Singleton, then it shouldn't be nullified. What version of driver do you use?

Comment: I am using Cassandra version 3.

Comment: No, I'm talking about java driver that you use to connect to cassandra. Latest is 3.5.1: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.5.1

Comment: Ok..I am using driver data stad 3.3.1, one issue i am seeing is that I am connecting to a cluster with 10 nodes. When any one of the node is down or lost connectivity for some reason, the session object is getting nullified. This is the root cause identified. How to handle this?

Comment: That’s very strange - newer have seen this. I recommend to try 3.5.1, and if it repeats, either file a JIRA, or at least ask in the mailing list